# Unable to Parse Date using NSDateFormatter

Tags: iphone, parsing, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am fetching a RSS, in which i receive the following Date stamp:

```
2010-05-10T06:11:14.000Z
```

Now i am using NSDateFormatter to parse this datetime stamp.

```
[parseFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dTH:m:s.z"];
```

But its not working fine if just remove the time stamp part it works for the date `[parseFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-d"];` But if i add the rest of the stuff it returns nil.

Any idea ?

Thanks in Advance....

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to parse zero padded values for d, H, m, s

You need to escape the literal `T` as `'T'`

You need to parse the fractional part of the seconds with `SSS`

You can accept a literal `Z` with `'Z'` or use uppercase Z to try and parse the timezone but RSS uses separate standard.

`@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"`

[Date Format Patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

Comment: Its working perfect, your suggestion really worked, zone is parsed and its returning +0005 now, and T is escaped.


Thanks a bunch again. :)

Answer (score 0):

From memory I've had this problem in the past as well. A couple of things to try:

1. Replace the "T" in your RSS feed with a space (and obviously change the date format string as well).
2. Your RSS feed has padded digits, where as your format string does not. Give this a try "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.Z". According to this link, that "z" should be capilized. http://www.stepcase.com/blog/2008/12/02/format-string-for-the-iphone-nsdateformatter/
3. Strip off the timezone info from the RSS feed and parse this manually. I seem to remember this causing problems for me.

Comment: Thanks for the handy link, and also for your suggestion :)