# How can I change the dateformat of the string in ios

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I have a string **2013-01-10T08:24:12.503** which is 'date' and 'time'.This is the format that I receive from my server.

I want to display this in the format 2013-01-10 08:24:12.
How can I do this?

Please help me out.

Comment: Try this...  NSString *string = @"2013-01-10T08:24:12.503";
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"T"
                                         withString:@"  "];
    NSLog(@"string..%@",string);

Comment: @Sudha post it as answer dude

Comment: @Dpk something wrong if I post it as a comment?

Comment: @Sudha: you wont earn points :D

Comment: @Sudha Nothing wrong! but it wont benefit you in any way! If you are sure that its the right answer, then post it as answer and get accepted!

Comment: @Sudha If it's a proper solution, it will be more accessible and readable by other users. Users don't tend to look in the comment section for credible answers.

Comment: Ok I posted it as a answer...

Comment: @Sudha better try your code and check whether you get the right answer as the question demands, before posting. No guess works please

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800780/unable-to-parse-date-using-nsdateformatter#answer-2800868)

Comment: @Sudha : I am able to get the output with string manipulation.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Sudha No way! You will be able to remove 'T' but wont get the last .503 from your method!You can't solve this without NSDateFormatter.Check the accepted answer

Comment: @Dpk : [string substringToIndex:[string length] - 4]; removes the last 4 characters but it is better to manipulate with the dateformatter.So I posted this question.Thanks for your response :)

Comment: @Pavitra this is not the way to solve this! "It is not better" use "It is the right way" in your comment yar

Comment: @Dpk : The right way is  " to use the dateformatter" :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23093/discussion-between-dpk-and-pavitra)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to esacpe the `T` string

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2013-01-10T08:24:12.503"];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
```

Using above format get normal `NSDate`

```
NSDate *formattedDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string];   // 2013-01-10 02:54:12 +0000
```

Again set the format you want

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Get the `String` you want,

```
NSString *curDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];    // 2013-01-10 08:24:12
```

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800780/unable-to-parse-date-using-nsdateformatter#answer-2800868), where i got reference.

Comment: +1 for very same answer, I was about to post. And no need to formatting again as you are formatting to default style.

Comment: +1, for the right answer! All other solutions here won't work

Answer (score -2):

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

 [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm"];



 NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:162000];



  NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

  NSLog(@"formattedDateString: %@", formattedDateString);
```

Comment: http://samplecodebank.blogspot.in/2011/05/nsdate-datewithtimeintervalsincereferen.html check this likn :)